# Order of the pole

Tags: complex-analysis

> What is the order of the pole at $z=0$:
>
> $$f(z)=\frac{1}{(2\cos(z)-2+z^2)^2}$$
>
> and find and classify the isolated singularities of:
>   $$\frac{1}{e^z-1}$$

My attempt:

If I let $f(z)=(2\cos(z)-2+z^2)^2$ then I get that:

$$f(z)=(2\cos(z)-2+z^2)^2 = [z^2-2+2\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!} z^{2n}]^2=[2\sum^{\infty}_{n=2} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!} z^{2n}]^2$$ but now I am having trouble finding th poles. I assumed that it is essential singularity at $0$, but the answer is $8$. I do not know why?

For the second part the answer is simple poles at $2n\pi i$. I get:
$$\frac{1}{e^z-1} = 
    \frac{1}{\sum^\infty_{n=0} {z^n\over n!} =1 + z + {z^2 \over 2!} + ... -1}=\frac{1}{z + {z^2 \over 2!} + ... }=\frac{1}{z}[\frac{1}{1+{z \over 2!}+... }]$$
but again I do not know why it is simple poles at $2n\pi i$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to go that far in the expansions.

You have $\cos z=1-\frac{z^2}{2}+\frac{z^4}{24}+O(z^6)$, hence $2\cos z-2+z^2=\frac{z^4}{12}(1+O(z^2))$. Finally
$$
f(z)=\frac{1}{\frac{z^8}{144}(1+O(z^2))^2}=\frac{144}{z^8}(1+O(z^2)).
$$
So the order of the pole is $8$ and the coefficient is $144$.

The set of zeros of $g(z)=e^z-1$ is indeed $2i\pi\mathbb{Z}$. Note that $g'(z)=e^z$ so $g'(2in\pi)=1$ at each zero. So
$$
\lim_{z\rightarrow 2in\pi}\frac{z-2in\pi}{g(z)}=\frac{1}{g'(2in\pi)}=1. 
$$
Therefore each zero of $g$ yields a pole of order $1$ (simple pole) with coefficient $1$ (also called the residue) for the function $\frac{1}{g(z)}=\frac{1}{e^z-1}$.

Both times, we used the following characterization: if $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}(z-z_0)^nf(z)=A\neq 0$, then $z_0$ is a pole of order $n$ of $f$ with coefficient $A$ (of course, the converse is true).

Comment: Thanks, Julien! Why exactly did you pull out a $z^4$?

Comment: @Q.matin Because that's the only thing that really matters here. We don't need the rest of the expansion to study the pole. In other words, $2\cos z-2+z^2\sim z^4/12$ is enough for what we want. See the characterization of poles I gave at the end of my answer.

Comment: I am sorry, I am still not following?

Comment: The function $h(z)=2\cos z-2+z^2$ behaves like $z^4/12$ near $0$ (that's the symbol $\sim$, it means that the quotient of the two functions tends to $1$ when $z$ tends to $0$). So $h(z)^2$ behaves like $(z^4/12)^2=z^8/144$. And finally your function $f(z)=1/h(z)^2$ behaves like $144/z^8$. This means that $z^8f(z)$ tends to $144$ at $0$. Now see the pole characterization I recalled. This means $0$ is an order $8$ pole with residue $144$.

Comment: The pole is of order 8, but the residue is 0. The residue is the coefficient of the $\frac{1}{z}$ term of the Laurent series, and according to Wolfram Alpha the Laurent series doesn't have a $\frac{1}{z}$ term.

Comment: @RandomVariable Ah, right, thanks. I don't know why I used the term residue. My mistake. I simply don't know how to call the coefficient above $z^8$... I'll call it coefficient.

Comment: Don't worry about it.  I make mistakes all the time.

Comment: @Q.matin Note that you should replace the word residue by coefficient in my previous comments. The answer was edited accordingly. Besides, I hope it is clear enough by now.

Comment: Julien, I am sorry, but I am still not understanding why you factored out $z^4$ which gives: $$f(z)=\left(2z^{-4}\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}z^{2n-4}\right)^{-2} = \frac{1}{(\frac{1}{2}z^4-\frac{2}{6!}z^6+...)^2}$$ so why do you need to factor out a $z^4$ and wouldn't it be an essential singularity because you have an infinite sum of series of $\frac{1}{z}$?

Comment: @Q.matin TO begin with, consider the enitre (ie holomorphic ont he whole complex plane) function $e^z=\sum_{n\geq 0} z^n/n!=1+z+z^2/2+\ldots$. It is nowhere zero, so $1/e^=e^{-z}$ is also entire and has no singularity. Note that $1/e^z=e^{z}=1/(1+z+z^2/2+\ldots)$.

Comment: @Q.matin So you have a misconception. If a function is of the form $1/\sum a_nz^n$, it does not mean it is of the form $\sum b_n/z^n$ with infinitely many nonzero $b_n$'s which means $0$ is en essential singularity. These are very different things. Actually, for a function of the former form $1/f(z)$ with $f$ holomorphic and nonzero around $0$, you can write $f(z)=z^k(a_0+a_1z+\ldots)$ with $a_0\neq 0$. Note that $k$ is the multiplicity of $0$ as a zero of $f$. Then $1/f=(1/z^k)(b_0+b_1z+\ldots)$ with $b_0=1/a_0\neq 0$. So $1/f(z)=c_{-k}/z^k+\ldots c_{-1}/z+c_0+c_1z+c_2z^2+\ldots$.

Comment: @Q.matin That's a Laurent series where you read that $0$ is a pole of order $k$. This is why you factor out the $z^4$. Then raising to the square, you get a $z^8$ times $1/144+\dots$. Finally, when you take the inverse, this means $0$ is a pole of order $8$ with coefficient $144$. With this in mind, I think you should read the answer and the comments again carefully. In particular the characterization of poles.

Comment: @Q.matin In the comment above, it should be $1/e^z=e^{-z}$.

Comment: @Q.matin Great. I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For the first part, you can factor a $z^4$ out of the denominator, and then since there is a square, you end up factoring a $z^{-8}$ out of $f(z)$. That is, you have $$f(z)=\left(2z^{-4}\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}z^{2n-4}\right)^{-2}=z^{-8}\cdot\left(2\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}z^{2n-4}\right)^{-2}.$$ Therefore,the order of the pole at $z=0$ is $8$.

For the second part, solve the equation $e^z-1=0$, perhaps by logarithms if you've learned those in your course. Otherwise, if $z=x+iy$, then you have $e^z=e^x(\cos y+i\sin y)=1$. Equating real and imaginary parts, we have the $y=n\pi$ for $n\in\Bbb Z$ (via the imaginary part since $e^x>0$). Now we can evaluate the real part and see that $y=2n\pi i$.

Comment: Thanks, Clayton! By why exactly did you factor out a $z^4$?

Comment: Because we want the first term of the power series to be nonzero when $z=0$. To get this result, we factor out the highest power of $z$ we can, which is $z^4$.

Comment: Sry, but I am still not following. Why do we want the first term of the power series to be nonzero?

Comment: We know that if $z_0$ is a pole of $f(z)$, then $f(z)$ can be written uniquely as $(z-z_0)^{-n}g(z)$ where $g(z)$ is nonvanishing at $z_0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!